# Returning IQueryable from within a using block. Need better design

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, using-statement

I have created a PhoneBook style application; on my phonebook object I have a local member `_site` which is used as a filter, since there are approximately 1000 phone numbers, split across 12 sites within my organisation. Only one site will be retrieved at a time using this method.

This was my original method. The GUI has several methods for reordering the data, so I left it as an IQueryable because I would like to defer SQL to allow for filtering to be done on the SQL server rather than on the client PC.

**Works**

```
public IQueryable<PhoneNumber> GetPhoneDirectory()
{
    PhoneBookDataContext db = new PhoneBookDataContext())
    return db.PhoneNumbers.Where(d => d.Site == _site);
}
```

However, I am also trying to keep to 'best practise' in terms of `using` statements.

**Doesn't Work**

```
public IQueryable<PhoneNumber> GetPhoneDirectory()
{
    using (PhoneBookDataContext db = new PhoneBookDataContext())
    {
        return db.PhoneNumbers.Where(d => d.Site == _site);
    }
}
```

Now as pointed out by @justanotheruseryoumay, this will cause an exception because the datacontext is disposed by the time the objects are accessed.

I guess what I am asking is, how can I make sure my data context is disposed nicely, when I cannot use a 'using' statement and don't strictly know when the context is done with.

Comment: Though I can't be sure, I believe the problem is that the `using` statement wouldn't be able to `Dispose` the object until it fell out of scope -which wouldn't happen until the query were to execute.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong here, but wont any local variables get marked for disposal the second a method returns? I assumed the two snippets above were essentially equivalent.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question, since I didn't clearly mention that the second throws an exception.

Comment: You should let @justanotheruseryoumayknow as it appears their answer is correct.

Comment: They deleted it, can't figure out how to contact them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to return `IQueryable` you can make your class that contains the `GetPhoneDirectory` disposable, make the `PhoneBookDataContext` a field, and dispose it in your dispose method.

You will then put the onus on the caller to dispose his instance of your class.

E.g.

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    PhoneBookDataContext db;

    public MyClass()
    {
        db = new PhoneBookDataContext();
    }

    public IQueryable<PhoneNumber> GetPhoneDirectory()
    {
        return db.PhoneNumbers.Where(d => d.Site == _site);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (db != null)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            db = null;
        }
    }
}

// Caller
using(var myClass = new MyClass())
{
    var queryable = myClass.GetPhoneDirectory();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah I like the look of this! My only question is what happens if somebody else inserts a record into PhoneNumbers between the time that somebody creates "MyClass" and then calls the method? Presumably I always get a fresh call to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

The execution of the query will still be deferred and the PhoneBookDataContext will still be properly Disposed because using is interpreted by the compile as a try/finally. When you actually execute the query it will result in a runtime error because the PhoneBookDataContext no longer exists. I would suggest doing a .ToList() on your query and returning it that way. If you want to change the order after you return it then you can still do LINQ on it as you please.

**EDIT:**
Another thing you could do is to create the using with the PhoneBookDataContext in the calling method and pass in the context. The context is really going to be used in that method anyway and you can keep it around as long as you need it and stick with the good using format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; It is bad design because your `IQueryable<PhoneNumber>` will be evaluated only when you call a method that cause it to be evaluated, like `ToList()` or when you iterate it with `foreach`.

in your code you are returning a `IQueryable<PhoneNumber>` which is not evaluated yet, and before the caller get any chance to execute it, it's internals that has the responsibility for yielding the records to you (db); is already disposed.

Just as a suggestion:

```
public IEnumerable<PhoneNumber> GetPhoneDirectory()
{
    using (PhoneBookDataContext db = new PhoneBookDataContext())
    {
        return db.PhoneNumbers.Where(d => d.Site == _site).ToList();
    }
}
```

Or relocate the db object to somewhere else in your design (Unit Of Work and Repository are  nice patterns to get a look at IMHO).